# Ansible variable usage. Jinja2 warning about delimiter usage

Tags: ansible, jinja2

> I know this looks like a duplicate question about this particular warning, however my use case is using the variable in a way that interprets as a literal string when the {{ brackets }} are removed

**ansible 2.8.1**

I have the following WORKING Ansible snippet, note the `when` clause:

```
- name: Set DNS for data host 1
  route53:
    command: create
    zone: "{{ dns_domain_name }}"
    record: "elasticsearch-{{ env }}-01"
    type: A
    ttl: 300
    value: "{{ ec2_private_ip_address }}"
    wait: no
    private_zone: True
    overwrite: yes
  when: tag_name is match("xhost-{{ env }}01")
```

I'm getting the following warning:

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: tag_name is
match("xhost-{{ env }}01")
```

If I remove the delimeter:

```
  when: tag_name is match("xhost-env01")
```

Won't work since it's part of the `match()` query string. I get no errors but the match query doesn't work.

**How can I handle this without getting the annoying warnings?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional variable and then use the variable in match().

```yaml
- name: Set DNS for data host 1
  route53:
    command: create
    zone: "{{ dns_domain_name }}"
    record: "elasticsearch-{{ env }}-01"
    type: A
    ttl: 300
    value: "{{ ec2_private_ip_address }}"
    wait: no
    private_zone: True
    overwrite: yes
  when: tag_name is match(matcher)
  vars:
    matcher: "xhost-{{ env }}01"
```